# using NSURL Launching iPhoneApp from another App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Im using this code to open AppStore app url , which is working fine am trying to launch then app it self not just open the appstore app page

any tips how i can do this using NSURL

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

NSURL *appStoreUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cnn-app-for-iphone/id331786748?mt=8"];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appStoreUrl];
      });
```

Comment: Check out the section "Implementing Custom URL Schemes" : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html To do what you are attempting you need to implement a custom URL scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only open the app itself if it supports a custom URL-scheme. Posting from Tweetbot is enabled by opening the url tweetbot:///post?

Alot of pages lists the urls you need to interact with other apps, see for instance http://handleopenurl.com/ or http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes for other examples and apps

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.com/apps/appname"]];
```